# How to Catch Errors in JavaScript Dropbox Datastore API

Tags: dropbox-api

I see options for catching errors when connecting to a datastore like this:

```
datastoreManager.openDefaultDatastore(function(error, datastore){
  if(error){
    alert(error); 
  }
});
```

But I'm unsure how to catch an error like when the datastore is too large:

[image]

I assume I would need to catch this after a failed insert. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A try/catch around the `insert` should work:

```
try {
    table.insert({
        field_name: large_value,
    });
} catch(err) {
    // error handling here
}
```

Comment: Ah, so it's just a general JS `try` / `catch` ... makes sense. Thank you!